# Kendo UI JSONP grid does not work

Tags: grid, jsonp, datasource, kendo-ui

I have this page below, in which the data: piece looks just like the JSONP from the server, but it does not show any data with this proof of concept.

Later on I hope to replace the data: section with

```
transport : {
read : "dwr/jsonp/DemoProxy/read/arg0",
dataType : "jsonp"
},
```

but let's first get the page below working.

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div id="grid0"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#grid0').kendoGrid({
                dataSource : {
                    data : [ {
                        "reply" : [ {
                            "location" : "dfg", "multi" : "dfg", "name" : "dfg"
                        }, {
                            "location" : "dfg", "multi" : "dfg", "name" : "dfg"
                        } ]
                    } ],
                    schema : {
                        data : "reply",
                        model : {
                            fields : {
                                location : {
                                    type : "string"
                                },
                                multi : {
                                    type : "string"
                                },
                                name : {
                                    type : "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                columns : [ {
                    field : "location", title : "Location"
                }, {
                    field : "multi", title : "Multi"
                }, {
                    field : "name", title : "Name"
                } ]
            });
        })
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why do you use different sources for KendoUI JavaScript and KendoUI CSS files? Watch out not mixing different releases.

Comment: Ow, that's just coincidence, I grabbed this example from the KendoUI site itsself. These versions are compatible. Thanx for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `data` in the `dataSource` as:

```
data  :{
    "reply":[
        { "location":"dfg", "multi":"dfg", "name":"dfg" },
        { "location":"dfg", "multi":"dfg", "name":"dfg" }
    ]
},
```

Since in `schema` you said that data is in `reply`, `data` is an `object` and not an `array`. What actually is an `array` is `reply`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Super thanx! However, when I remove the data: section and add the transport: section as above, it doesn't work. The server is giving back exactly what is stated in the data section: {"reply":[{"location":null,"multi":null,"name":""},{"location":null,"multi":null,"name":""}]}

Comment: But if the server is sending back a lot of `null`... that's a different question, no?